# How to migrate large collection from MongoDB (remote) to MySQL (remote)

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

I am trying to create a python script to migrate few collections from MongoDB (deployed on Atlas) to RDS MySQL server as part of data pipeline. I am able to migrate small collections but I am facing issue with large collections.

I import every collection using Pymongo package and find() and creating a data frame for it. Then using "df.to_sql", collection is migrated to MySQL instance. But there is one collection with around 1 million documents. It created a data frame of dimension 1000000 x 50 and memory is not able to handle data frame of this size. So I tried migrating it by dividing collection in parts. I fetched 100,000 documents, convert it to data frame and load it to MySQL but in this method also I faced different issue. After 4-5 iterations I got error "MySQL server has gone away".
What can be possible solution to migrate big collection to MySQL?

Comment: Does your mysql have enough resources to handle the load?

Comment: You can export mongo collections as csv. And mysql can accept csv as an import. In my experience, this is the quickest way (in terms of import run time).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Current MySQL server is hosted on AWS t2.medium instance (4 GB RAM).

Comment: Exporting this large collection will create csv of huge size, which will again be problem also not every document in collection is having same fields or same number of fields.

Comment: "also not every document in collection is having same fields or same number of fields." - looks like you already know how to handle this in your python script, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: parsing is not an issue as I migrated the small collections, I am facing issue with large size collections, I am struggling to find an efficient way to migrate large collections.